# Equivalent of Junit 4's @RunWith annotation in Junit 3.8

Tags: java, junit

What it the equivalent of using the @RunWith annotation for Junit 3.8? I've searched for a while on this, but Junit 3.8 is much older and I haven't been able to find much on the subject. We are using a 1.4 jre so Junit 4 is out of the question to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we can use Junit 4 to execute tests with Junit 3.8 by using the Junit38ClassRunner which is included in Junit 4.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly we used to do our own TestRunner implementations that our suites extended.

Comment: We're trying not to take that route, though after perusing the JUnit 4 source code we see how they implement it. There was no built in way for this in 3.x though?