# JUnit/Cucumber- Can @RunWith(Cucumber.class) be simulated prior to JUnit4?

Tags: eclipse, junit, cucumber

I'm currently working on a Java project in which we are using Cucumber to test some features. The team is using an older version of JUnit, so that the @RunWith annotation cannot be used without adding a newer version of JUnit to the build path. Here lies my problem: For some reason, JUnit4 breaks the build on Jenkins. It compiles fine locally, but it seems to break cause build failures when we build on Jenkins.

Is there something similar to the @RunWith(Cucumber.class) annotation that I can make without the need for JUnit4? Currently, this is all I need it for:

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class CukeRunner { }
```

So is there a  way to make this compatible with versions of JUnit that don't support @RunWith? Thanks in advance,

Comment: This is obviously not an answer to your question, but it seems like it would be a better investment of your time and effort to fix the *real* problem, i.e. *"For some reason, JUnit4 breaks the build on Jenkins"*, doesn't it? Junit 3 is pretty much obsolete (somebody asked [almost identical question exactly **3 years ago**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6734867/1240557))

Comment: Thanks for your response, kryger. The team and I sat down and took a look at what broke and it was only a single test, so we'll just go about making that compatible with JUnit4.